# LatLngBounds - how to get SW and NE points

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use Google Maps' autocomplete and bias results to `LatLngBounds`. I'd like to be able to draw a rectangle around an island (say the Hawaiian islands) and get the LatLngBounds that way. Is there any tool I can use to help me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A long time ago I wrote a "Zoom window" that I adapted for your use. It's just map and rectangle listeners.

http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/16/embedded/result/

to see code:

http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/16/

To use it, first zoom in and pan manually to your island. The whole area you want to select must be visible on-screen.

Then click once to define a rectangle corner. Move the mouse towards the diagonally opposite corner. (A rectangular selection will appear). Click again to define the rectangular area. The textarea above the map should give you the selected LatLngBounds with SW and NE points.

It just doesn't behave as expected when trying to contain the International Date Line.

```
  var map;

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
    zoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var bounds;
  var pt1, pt2;
  var rect;

  function toLatLng(lat, lng) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  }

  function toBounds(j,k) {
    var pts = [];
    var latMin, latMax, lngMin, lngMax;
    var sw, ne;

    latMin = Math.min(j.lat(), k.lat());
    latMax = Math.max(j.lat(), k.lat());

    lngMin = Math.min(j.lng(), k.lng());
    lngMax = Math.max(j.lng(), k.lng());

    sw = toLatLng(latMin, lngMin);
    ne = toLatLng(latMax, lngMax);
    return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
  }

  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    rect = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      fillColor: "#FFFF00",
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      strokeColor: "#0000FF",
      strokeWeight: 2
    });

    // Activate the box
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      pt1 = event.latLng;
      rect.setMap(map);
    });

    // Modify the box's size
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
      if(rect.getMap() == map) {
        rect.setBounds(toBounds(pt1, event.latLng));
      }
    });

    // Remove the zoom window and zoom in
    google.maps.event.addListener(rect, 'click', function(event) {
      rect.setMap(null);
      pt2 = event.latLng;
      myBounds = toBounds(pt1, pt2);

      document.getElementById("selectedBounds").value = "new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng" + myBounds.getSouthWest() + ", new google.maps.LatLng" + myBounds.getNorthEast() + ");";
    });

    // Allows shrinking the box
    google.maps.event.addListener(rect, 'mousemove', function(event) {
      if(rect.getMap() == map) {
        rect.setBounds(toBounds(pt1, event.latLng));
      }
    });
  }
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="selectedBounds" cols="60" rows="4"></textarea>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>​
```

Comment: Awesome answer; i wish I could give bonus points for the example. Maybe you can also post the code here, so that it won't get lost in the future.

Comment: This tool is EXACTLY what I was hoping for. You should put this up on a website so others can use it. Thanks!

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie I do have a plan of cleaning up and packaging a bunch of maps tools for my website, but Stack Overflow keeps distracting me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another similar tool which has no problem with the anti-meridian:
http://maps.forum.nu/gm_drag_polygon.html

Marcelo.

Comment: This link is now invalid.