# Google Maps Autocomplete: how to get lat/lng?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps' autocomplete feature for geocoding. It seems to return a lot of data, but not the lat/lng. Is there a way to get this information? I'd like to pass it back to my backend application for further processing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LatLngBounds - how to get SW and NE points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957559/latlngbounds-how-to-get-sw-and-ne-points)

Comment: You're just firing a lot of questions (429 questions vs 15 answers) without properly describing that you want to do or what you've tried to solve it yourself. It adds noise to this website.

Comment: They aren't duplicates. One deals with trying to determine a rectangle and this one deals with the response the API returns.

Comment: Do you mean Places autocomplete? Would you provide more information, maybe some code if it's not too verbose?

Comment: I'm using this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK, I'm not familiar with Places or Autocomplete. But it looks like what you are looking for is

```
autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location
```

To demonstrate I took [this example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) and added the line above to create [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/19/) where you can enter the place name and when it's selected, an infowindow with the LatLng is created.

In particular it listens to the user's selection, then refreshes the infowindow.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       ...
      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + 
        '</strong><br>' + address + "<br>" + place.geometry.location);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't brings long and lat.

Comment: @neoplomero actually it does, having `autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location` you can access `autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat()` and `autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng()`

Comment: How can I get Geometry property?

Answer (score 63):

There are methods called lat() and lng() that exist on the geometry object's prototype. So to get the values, just use the following:

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

var lat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
    lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

// Then do whatever you want with them

console.log(lat);
console.log(lng);

console.warn('Warning: I didn\'t test this code!');
```

Comment: Does this use up requests in the quota?

Comment: @DavidTan Yes, the Google Places API Web Service and Place Autocomplete share a usage quota. If you're over your limit, the `status` filed will have a string value of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. You can read about the limits here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage

Answer (score 23):

The other answers are missing a critical component. You need to include `'geometry'` when you call `setFields`. Be aware that more fields may cost more.

Ex:

```
// Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
// place fields that are returned to just the address components.
autocomplete.setFields(['address_component', 'geometry']);
```

[See docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)